Quadratic equation in finite fields.
Let $F_q$ be any finite field (I am not sure whether the characteristic or the order should matter).
Given $a,b \in F_q$, is there an algorithm for finding the solution of the equation
$$ x^2+ax=y^2+by$$
in $F_q$?

Of course: You only need to plug in all of the finitely many elements of $\mathbb{F}_q$ into the equation!

Assume first that $q$ is odd implying that $1/2\in\Bbb{F}_q$.
You can rewrite the equation in the form
$$
(x+\frac a2)^2-(y+\frac b2)^2=\frac{a^2-b^2}4.\qquad(*)
$$
On the left we see a difference of two squares, so using the factorization $(m^2-n^2)=(m+n)(m-n)$ is strongly indicated. So we introduce new variables
$$
\begin{aligned}
u&=(x+y+\frac{a+b}2),\\
v&=(x-y+\frac{a-b}2),
\end{aligned}
$$
and the constant
$$K=\frac{a^2-b^2}4.$$
Observe that $u+v=2x+a$ and $u-v=2y+b$, so it is trivial to go back to the original variables $x,y$ whenever we wish.
Anyway, the equation has been transformed into
$$
uv=K.\qquad(**)
$$
Finding all the solutions $(u,v)$ of $(**)$ is very straightforward. If $K\neq0$ we can let $v$ be any non-zero element, and solve $u=K/v$. This leads to $q-1$ solutions $(u,v)$ and hence also to $q-1$ solutions $(x,y)$, easily parametrizable.
I leave it as an exercise to list all the solutions of $(**)$ when $K=0$ (i.e. $a=\pm b$).

When $q$ is even (so $q=2^m$) a different approach is needed. The main point is that the equation is linear over the prime field $\Bbb{F}_2$. In other words, the solutions $(x,y)$ form a vector subspace $V$ of the $2m$-dimensional subspace of $\Bbb{F}_q^2$. In other words, if $(x_1,y_1)$ and $(x_2,y_2)$ are solutions, so is $(x_1+x_2,y_1+y_2)$.
This time I assume $a\neq0\neq b$ for in the other cases it is easy to prove that
$\dim V=m$. It is a standard fact that an element $v\in \Bbb{F}_q$ is of the form $x^2+ax$ if and only if $tr(v/a^2)=0$, where $tr:\Bbb{F}_q\to\Bbb{F}_2$ is the trace:
$$
tr(x)=x+x^2+x^4+\ldots +x^{2^{m-1}}.
$$
So, if $W\subset\Bbb{F}_q$ is the $(m-1)$-dimensional kernel of the trace map, the value of the left hand side is in the $(m-1)$-dimensional subspace $a^2W$. Similarly, the right hand side takes values in the $(m-1)$-dimensional subspace $b^2W$. Such subspaces go through all the $(m-1)$-dimensional subspaces of $\Bbb{F}_q$. In particular, $a^2W=b^2W$ if and only if $a=b$. The mappings $x\mapsto x^2+ax$ and $y\mapsto y^2+by$ are both 2-to-1 (with kernels spanned by $a$ and $b$ respectively). This means that to each $z\in a^2W\cap b^2W$ there are four solutions. The dimension of that intersection is either $m-2$ or $m-1$, with the latter alternative occuring if and only if $a=b$. The space of solution $V$ has thus dimension $m$ or $m+1$. The above reasoning suggests several ways of finding
a basis for $V$. The details of how to best do that may depend on how do you represent the field $\Bbb{F}_q$ in your program, so I will stop at this point for now.

Brute force will do: $\mathbb{F}_q$ has finitely many elements; take all $q^2$ pairs of such elements and plug them in for $x$ and $y$ until you either find a solution or exhaust the search space.

Ok, sure, but can we say something about, for example, the number of pairs that solve it, given $a$ and $b$?

@User Run the algorithm until you've found all the pairs ¯\(ツ)/¯. If you're interested about the mathematical properties of $x^2 + ax = y^2 + by$, ask a new question.

Since $q$ could be large, I'll just mention there's a linear time algorithm, where you plug in a value for $y$, then use the quadratic formula to solve for $x$. This is the best you can do if you're listing solutions, since there can be $O(q)$ of them.
